# passing arguments to class correctly - Kivy gui

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I'm trying to learn OOP and tinkering with Kivy, I've done an opening page with a background image and a logo which functions as a button, so far so good.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage, Image
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior  
from kivy.uix.image import Image

# dir 
src='C:\\Users\\Scott\\projects\\Kivy\\botGUI\\static\\ims\\mainResize.png'
src2='C:\\Users\\Scott\\projects\\Kivy\\botGUI\\static\\ims\\etoro.png'

# make window same size as background image:
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '960')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')

class rootWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(rootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=src))

# use logos in dir for buttons
class myButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): 
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(myButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'C:\\Users\\Scott\\projects\\Kivy\\botGUI\\static\\ims\\etoro.png'
        self.size_hint=(.25,.25)
        self.pos_hint={'center_x':.15,'center_y':.85}

    def on_press(self):  
        print ('etoro pressed')     

class mainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = root = rootWidget()
        root.add_widget(myButton())  
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```

the next step would be to iterate over the sub-directory and create a button for each logo so I don't have to hardcode them in, so as a first step I alter the myButton class to remove the harcoded info in the class:

## current

```
class myButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): 
    def __init__(self,src,xs,ys,xc,yc):
        self.src = src
        self.xs = xs
        self.ys = ys
        self.xc = xc
        self.yc = yc
        super(myButton, self).__init__()

    def drawButton(self):
        self.source = src
        self.size_hint=(xs,ys)
        self.pos_hint={'center_x':xc,'center_y':yc}

    def on_press(self):  
        print ('pressed',src)
```

and tweek the build method:

```
class mainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = root = rootWidget()
        root.add_widget(myButton(src2,0.1,0.1,0.,0.).drawButton)


        return root
```

this throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "t.py", line 60, in <module>
     mainApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Scott\projects\Kivy\envs\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "t.py", line 54, in build
     root.add_widget(myButton(src2,0.1,0.1,0.,0.).drawButton)
   File "C:\Users\Scott\projects\Kivy\envs\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 135, in add_widget
     widget.bind(
 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

My question is, am I using the class and passing the arguments correctly but have made a mistake else where (my suspicion is the super) or am I missing something with respect to OO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root.add_widget(myButton(src2,0.1,0.1,0.,0.).drawButton)
```

drawButton is a method of the class, but `add_widget` expects to receive a widget as its argument.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i don't think i follow it, why am i passing it as a widget in the first case where i hardcode everything, but not in the second case when i try to abstract it?

Comment: I don't know why you are doing that, it's your code. The problem is that it's wrong, you need to pass a widget as the argument in every case.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this might help someone else, I was misunderstanding how to use OO as well as what I was trying to do in Kivy!

```
# current
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior  
from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivy.uix.label import Label
import os

rootDir='C:\\Users\\Scott\\projects\\Kivy\\botGUI\\static\\ims\\logos\\'
contents = os.listdir(rootDir)

bkgrd='C:\\Users\\Scott\\projects\\Kivy\\botGUI\\static\\ims\\mainResize.png'

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '960')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '600')

class rootWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(rootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(AsyncImage(source=bkgrd))


class myButton(ButtonBehavior, Image): 
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(myButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_press(self):  
        print ('pressed',self.source)


class mainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = root = rootWidget()
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        for logo in contents:
            path = rootDir+logo
            layout.add_widget(myButton(source=path))

        root.add_widget(layout)


        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainApp().run()
```